# How to construct a no-op IO() expression in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, monads, io-monad

Here's an excerpt of a domain-specific file-IO function I'm writing:

```
let
    cp :: FilePath -> IO ()
    cp "." = putStr "" -- OUCH!
    cp ".." = putStr "" -- CRIKEY!
    cp fname = custom logic here...
in mapM_ cp filepaths
```

I understand `mapM_` lets us drop/ignore all `IO ()` results, so I'd like a cleaner alternative to `putStr ""` --- ie. Haskell's "canonical" way to write "a type-correct no-op IO (or monad) expression that does nothing".

From my newbie reading I had `undefined` in mind, and while this compiles and causes no issues, it gives an unwanted stdout print `main.hs: Prelude.undefined` (I use `stack runghc main.hs` as the *sole* coding environment here --- it's just sufficient for this, *but* the above code will be looping recursively through directory trees: so would be a good time to (re)learn about a better, or rather "the proper" way).

Comment: try `cp "." = return ()`

Comment: @haoformayor: That should be an answer :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an unfortunate aspect of Haskell's learning curve: you would think there should be some sort of library function called

```
doNothing :: IO ()
```

for you to use, but the ecosystem expects you to know of the `return` function in the `Monad` typeclass, one of the many typeclasses that `IO` instances. In this case `return ()` should produce the intended behavior of creating an `IO` action (read: effect, or thunk, or promise) that does nothing.

You might also be interested in [`listDir` and `copyFile` from the `path-io` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/path-io-1.0.1/docs/Path-IO.html#v:copyFile), which by using stronger types than `type FilePath = String` is able to do away with the whole problem of `.` and `..` altogether. Note in particular how `listDir` returns subdirectories and files separately in a tuple. If that is not in the spirit of Haskell then what is? It does bring in an external dependency however but I am always looking for situations to plug that excellent library.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, the timely `return` reminder and the recommendation! (Yes for this one-off I want zero-config, zero-dependencies and instant-runghc-ability on any machine with just vanilla stack. But for other work path-io sounds excellent.)